# Change the CSS class of a span element on mouseover of another element

Tags: javascript, css, onmouseover, onmouseout

I am trying to change the css class of a span element when another element is hovered over. The get an idea of what I mean. Load up your Facebook and hover over the main newsfeed posts and in the top right the little down-arrow appears.

That is the effect that I want to create.
So far I have:

```
<li id="unique" class="message"><a href="javascript:void(0)" onMouseOver="(MC.className='messageControls')" onMouseOut="(MC.className='hidden')" onclick="callTheFunction();"></li>

<span id="MC" class="hidden">hksdjhkjsdhfkjhsdkjh</span>
```

But this doesn't work. Any pointers? I don't want to use any frameworks/libraries such as jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `on..` event handlers have no concept of what `MC` is.  Try like this:

```
... onMouseOver="document.getElementById('MC').className='messageControls'" ...
```

This way you "look up" the element with the `id` attribute whose value is `MC`, then act on that element.  And as a remdinder, elements must have unique IDs.

Comment: I had that already (sorry I should have said I have stored that in a variable before hand) but even when put in the literal value it still doesn't work.